# different methods of regTermTest() in survey package

Tags: r, survey

I am trying to compare different Cox models to choose the “best” model. I am working with NHANES data and therefore use the survey package. With the svycoxph function the lrtest(), BIC(), AIC() and anova() don’t work.
There is the function regTermTest() in the survey package. I am not really sure if I can use this function with the method=”LRT” to compare models or how it works.

```
library("survey")
 
NHANES_all <- svydesign(data=data_all, id=~Total.PSU, strata=~Total.stratum, weights=~Total.final.weight, nest=TRUE)
NHANES_subset <- subset(NHANES_all, cohortsubset==1)
 
M3<-svycoxph(Surv(PERMTH_INT, MORTSTAT==1)~relevel(group, ref = "2")  + Age.at.interview..screener....qty + relevel(Sex, ref = "2") + Race.ethnicity + relevel(education, ref = "2") + relevel(pirgroup, ref = "2")+ relevel(Marital.status, ref = "3") +  AlcFactCox + smoke + caffeinDec + LTPA + Body.mass.index + relevel(diabetes, ref = "2") + relevel(highBP, ref = "2") + eGFRgroup, subset(NHANES_subset, HS.primary.finding..recode==1))
 
regTermTest(M3, ~AlcFactCox + smoke, method="LRT", df=NULL)
 
> regTermTest(M3, ~AlcFactCox + smoke, method="LRT", df=NULL)
Working (Rao-Scott+F) LRT for AlcFactCox smoke
in svycoxph(formula = Surv(PERMTH_INT, MORTSTAT == 1) ~ relevel(group,
    ref = "2") + Age.at.interview..screener....qty + relevel(Sex,
    ref = "2") + Race.ethnicity + relevel(education, ref = "2") +
    relevel(pirgroup, ref = "2") + relevel(Marital.status, ref = "3") +
    AlcFactCox + smoke + caffeinDec + LTPA + Body.mass.index +
    relevel(diabetes, ref = "2") + relevel(highBP, ref = "2") +
    eGFRgroup,
    design = subset(NHANES_subset, HS.primary.finding..recode ==
        1))
Working 2logLR =  206.8198 p= 2.52e-07
(scale factors:  1.3 1 0.69 );  denominator df= 11
 
> regTermTest(M3, ~AlcFactCox + smoke, method="Wald", df=NULL)
Wald test for AlcFactCox smoke
in svycoxph(formula = Surv(PERMTH_INT, MORTSTAT == 1) ~ relevel(group,
    ref = "2") + Age.at.interview..screener....qty + relevel(Sex,
    ref = "2") + Race.ethnicity + relevel(education, ref = "2") +
    relevel(pirgroup, ref = "2") + relevel(Marital.status, ref = "3") +
    AlcFactCox + smoke + caffeinDec + LTPA + Body.mass.index +
    relevel(diabetes, ref = "2") + relevel(highBP, ref = "2") +
    eGFRgroup,
    design = subset(NHANES_subset, HS.primary.finding..recode ==
        1))
F =  42.20666  on  3  and  11  df: p= 2.5134e-06
```

In my example above with the method="LRT": do I compare the model M3 with its confounders with the model M3 without the confounders smoke and AlcfactCox? If I use the method=”Wald”, do I test if the estimated effect of both my tested confounders (smoke and AlcfactCox) is zero?

So basically my question is if the regTermTest() with method="LRT" is the right way to compare different svycoxph models or do you have any suggestions what is the best method or function to compare svycoxph models?

If I use the summary() function on my model, I get a concordance. But in my understanding, concordance is not sensitive enough for model comparison.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The different `method` arguments for `regTermTest` have the same null hypothesis, that the coefficients involved in the term you specify are all zero.

They differ in how the test is done. The Wald test is just the Wald test: it's based on $\hat\beta$ and its estimated variance. It's got the same sort of $\chi^2$ or $F$ null distribution that it always has.

The LRT is based on the weighted (pseudo)likelihood. This isn't a real likelihood, so we can't just apply the same theory as for simple random sampling, but it is still a test statistic: it's small when the two models are close and large when they aren't.  What we need is to work out the sampling distribution.  This has been done: the initial work for generalised linear models by Rao and Scott in the 1980s, and the extension to Cox models in 2013 by [me and Scott](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/22806928/).

In difficult situations (small numbers of clusters in the survey) the LRT has closer to its nominal Type I error rate, but typically has slightly lower power.

Here's an example, using a model that comes from `?svycoxph`

```
> model<-svycoxph(Surv(time,status>0)~log(bili)+protime+albumin,design=dpbc)
> regTermTest(model, ~protime+albumin,method="LRT")
Working (Rao-Scott+F) LRT for protime albumin
 in svycoxph(formula = Surv(time, status > 0) ~ log(bili) + protime + 
    albumin, design = dpbc)
Working 2logLR =  33.29058 p= 2.1805e-07 
(scale factors:  1.1 0.9 );  denominator df= 307
> regTermTest(model, ~protime+albumin)
Wald test for protime albumin
 in svycoxph(formula = Surv(time, status > 0) ~ log(bili) + protime + 
    albumin, design = dpbc)
F =  17.60387  on  2  and  307  df: p= 5.7843e-08
```

The Wald test is using a straightforward F distribution; the LRT is using a more complicated distribution that's a linear combination of chi-squareds.

Answer (score -1):

I also find regTermTest() did not work for svycoxph()